# How can I scrape a table's header that contains an image?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table from a wiki website, by using pandas library, the header consists of 5 parts: name, stars, image, health, notes.
I successfully scraped name, stars and notes, but the "Health" header has an image instead of a string name.
(I would like to display "Health" as a string instead of an image.)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

url = pd.read_html("https://azurlane.koumakan.jp/List_of_Cargo#Min_Stats")

print("Type eq name: ")
eq_name = input(str())

#   list of cargo
if eq_name == "Type94".casefold():
        #   40cm Type 94
        df = url[1]
        df = df.drop([1, 2, 3], axis = 0)
        name_notes = df[['Name','Stars','Health','Notes']]
        print(name_notes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = url[1]
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 3':'Health'}, inplace=True)
```

result:

|  | Name | Image | Stars | Health | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 40cm Type 94 Naval Gun Parts (Cargo) | nan | ★★★★★ | 450 | Gun Components: When equipped by Kashino: increases the FP of your Main Fleet and your CBs by 10%. |
| 1 | Aviation Materials (Cargo) | nan | ★★★★ | 250 | Aviation Materials: When equipped by a Munition Ship: increases the AVI of your fleet by 8%. |
| 2 | Small-Caliber Naval Gun Parts (Cargo) | nan | ★★★★ | 250 | Small-Caliber Gun Parts: When equipped by a Munition Ship: increases the FP of your Vanguard by 8%. |
| 3 | Torpedo Materials (Cargo) | nan | ★★★★ | 250 | Torpedo Materials: When equipped by a Munition Ship: increases the TRP of your fleet by 8%. |